# Python subprocess output blocking on application prompt

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, output, stdout

I am running jirashell in a python script using the subprocess library. I am currently having issues having the outputs print in real time. When I run jirashell it outputs information than prompts the user (y/n). The subprocess won't print out information prior to the prompt until I enter 'y' or 'n'.

The code I am using is

```
_consumer_key = "justin-git"
_cmd = "jirashell -s {0} -od -k {1} -ck {2} -pt".format(JIRA_SERVER,
    _rsa_private_key_path, _consumer_key)
p = subprocess.Popen(_cmd.split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)

out, err = p.communicate() # Blocks here

print out
print err
```

The output is like so:

```
n # I enter a "n" before program will print output.
Output:
Request tokens received.
    Request token:        asqvavefafegagadggsgewgqqegqgqge
    Request token secret: asdbresbdfbrebsaerbbsbdabweabfbb
Please visit this URL to authorize the OAuth request:
        http://localhost:8000/plugins/servlet/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
Have you authorized this program to connect on your behalf to http://localhost:8000? (y/n)
Error:
Abandoning OAuth dance. Your partner faceplants. The audience boos. You feel shame.
```

Does anyone know how I can have it print the output prior to the prompt than wait for an input of y/n? Note I also need to be able to store the output produced by the command so "os.system()" won't work...

EDIT:

It looks like inside jirashell there is a part of the code that is waiting for an input and this is causing the block. Until something is passed into this input nothing is outputted... Still looking into how I can get around this. I'm in the process of trying to move the portion of code I need into my application. This solution doesn't seem elegant but I can't see any other way right now.

```
approved = input(
    'Have you authorized this program to connect on your behalf to {}? (y/n)'.format(server))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method which prints and caches the standard output:**

You can use a thread which reads the standard output of your subprocess, while the main thread is blocked until the subprocess is done. The following example will run the program `other.py`, which looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Hello")
x = input("Type 'yes': ")
```

Example:

```
import threading
import subprocess
import sys

class LivePrinter(threading.Thread):
    """
    Thread which reads byte-by-byte from the input stream and writes it to the
    standard out. 
    """
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream
        self.log = bytearray()
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # read one byte from the stream
            buf = self.stream.read(1)

            # break if end of file reached
            if len(buf) == 0:
                break

            # save output to internal log
            self.log.extend(buf)

            # write and flush to main standard output
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(buf)
            sys.stdout.flush()

# create subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('./other.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Create reader and start the thread
r = LivePrinter(p.stdout)
r.start()

# Wait until subprocess is done
p.wait()

# Print summary
print(" -- The process is done now -- ")
print("The standard output was:")
print(r.log.decode("utf-8"))
```

The class `LivePrinter` reads every byte from the subprocess and writes it to the standard output. (I have to admit, this is not the most efficient approach, but a larger buffer size blocks, the `LiveReader` until the buffer is full, even though the subprocess is awaiting the answer to a prompt.) Since the bytes are written to sys.stdout.buffer, there shouldn't be a problem with multi-byte utf-8 characters.

The `LiveReader` class also stores the complete output of the subprocess in the variable `log` for later use.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865229/run-subprocess-inside-python-thread-reading-the-output-in-realtime#31868783) answer summarizes, it is save to start a thread *after* forking with subprocess.

---

**Original answer which has problems, when the prompt line doesn't end a line:**

The output is delayed because `communicate()` blocks the execution of your script until the sub-process is done (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

You can read and print the standard output of the subprocess, while it is executed using `stdout.readline`. There are some issues about buffering, which require this rather complicated `iter(process.stdout.readline, b'')` construct. The following example uses `gpg2 --gen-key` because this command starts an interactive tool.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["gpg2", "--gen-key"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for stdout_line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(stdout_line.rstrip())
```

---

**Alternative answer which uses `shell` and does not cache the output:**

As Sam pointed out, there is a problem with the above solution, when the prompt line does not end the line (which prompts they usually don't). An alternative solution is to use the `shell` argument to interact with the sub-process.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("gpg2 --gen-key", shell=True)
```

Comment: I tried this out and it didn't seem to work. I even created two python scripts to test this. One with the code you mentioned, and another script that has a raw_input in the middle of two print statements. Nothing is outputted til an input is given.

Comment: Ok, I see. The problem is probably, that the prompt is not read because it does not end the line. If the other script is something like `print("Hello"); x = input("Please type 'yes': ")` only `Hello` is printed. I agree, my answer, does not solve the problem then.

Comment: Makes sense. I looked at the source code and it seems the library I am calling also uses a `print("Hello"); x = input("Please type 'yes': ")` Do you know a work around this?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an alternative solution using the `shell` argument.

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like it's not the shell that allows for the output but rather using subprocess.call() method. It has stdout=None, stderr=None, stdin=None default so outputs are not redirected to PIPE. Unfortunately I need to also need to be able to store the output the command produces but it looks like subprocess.call just outputs "1" or "0" for return, this call reminds me of os.system... Do you know if I can grab the output from using subprocess.call?

Comment: can't you use `shell` with `subprocess.Popen()` to redirect the stdin/stdout?

Comment: @cowbert I have tried to set `shell=True` in `subprocess.Popen()` but it also blocks at `p.communicate()`

Comment: @sauerburger I had to change `super().__init__()` to `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` and `sys.stdout.buffer.write(buf)` to `sys.stdout.write(buf)` for your script to work. Might be because you're using python 3. I'm using python 2.7.6. Still though it gets blocked at the `buf = self.stream.read(1)` until an input is outputted.

Comment: Indeed, I tested the code on python 3. python 2 seems to buffer the stdout, whereas `read(1)` in python3 is able to read the byes immediately.